# html section jump with <a name="something"> more than once?

Tags: html, xhtml, anchor

I have a simple

```
<a name="top"></a>
```

and another link:

```
<a href="#top">Back to Top of Page</a>
```

it works but after the first time the url turns to:

```
www.site.com/#top
```

and it doesn't work after a user uses it one time.
How can I make it so it will work multiple times?

Comment: "it doesn't work" -  _what_ doesn't work? What do you expect to work?

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need to use an `a` tag with a name, you can reference an `id` of an element instead. It helps to reduce the number of miscellaneous tags scattered about your page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this before. Can you test in different browsers and see if behavior is consistent? Try restarting browser, also.